# How to use java websockets on separate machines?

Tags: java, websocket

I have created a sample chat application using websockets which is running good on same machine. I want run client and server on separate machines.
But I am confused how to use websockets on separate machines, as actions of websocket (i.e onopen, onclose, onmessage etc) are happened with corresponding events.
How can I run websocket client and server on separate machine?

Comment: Make up your mind. Do you want to use RMI? Or web sockets? They aren't the same thing.

Comment: hey @EJP, I know both things are different. **I just want to run websocket server and websocket client on different machines**. RMI is one of the solution that can be used in such scenario, i.e. "running server and client on different machine". But if the server and clients are using websocket, I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: So therefore your question has nothing to do with RMI whatsoever, and mentioning it only adds to the confusion. I suggest you clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I wanted to just put what approach I have tried. Yes my main goal is to run web sockets on separate machine. Thanks for making question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In your client where you have written something like this: `ws://localhost:8080/`, replace your `localhost` by your different system's ip address from where you want to send the command.

But both machines should be on the same network.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a message broker (like RabbitMQ) which would take messages from your server and client would subscribe to the same broker and recieve messages as they are sent from server. Server needs to broadcast message to broker (exchange on broker) with a routing key and this routing key will bind to a queue and client would subscribe to this exchange with the same key (some common session).

Comment: Why? Web sockets can already do all the communication required. You don't need to add yet another technology.

Comment: @EJP In order to make your socket communication async and scalable, you always need a broker.